# Getting folder path using msoFileDialogFolderPicker

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which picks file from a SourcePath then renames it and saves in DestPath. The code is working fine with hardcoded folder path for SourcePath (SourcePath = "C:\Invoices\Raw invoices"). however, it's not able to capture and retain the folderpath with msoFileDialogFolderPicker function. The code is unable to find the file in sourcepath and gives error as programmed.

Here is the sample data.

[image]

Here is the code I am using.

```
Sub Rename_invoices()
    Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, Fname As String, NewFName As String
    Dim i As Long
    SourcePath = GetFolder("C:\")
    DestPath = "C:\Dunning Temp\"
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
            NewFName = Range("B" & i).Value
            'Search for the first file containing the string in column A
            Fname = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & Range("A" & i).Value & "*")
            If Fname <> vbNullString Then
                FileCopy SourcePath & Fname, DestPath & NewFName
            Else
                MsgBox Range("A" & i).Value & " dosen't exist in the folder"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.Close = False
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. `SourcePath` is definitely captured in your `GetFolder` function and retained inside your loop the entire time. Looks like it works as intended

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code or using `Debug.Print` to check the value of `SourcePath`?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add a backslash? I don't think the result of `GetFolder` would end in one.

Comment: @BigBen Great! I've got what I was missing. you are correct! Please post the suggestion as answer (SourcePath = GetFolder & "\") so that I can mark it as answered. Thank you so much for looking into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path your `GetFolder` Function returns will not end with a backslash `\`. As is, the *pathname* argument you pass to `Dir` in `Fname = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & Range("A" & i).Value & "*")` will be incorrect.

So change `SourcePath = GetFolder("C:\")` to `SourcePath = GetFolder("C:\") & "\"`, or add a trailing backslash within your `GetFolder` function.

As [@Mistella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9259306/mistella) pointed out, using `Debug.Print` would easily highlight this issue.